# Python 3 tries to run Python 2 on subprocess (Windows)

Tags: python, subprocess, arcgis

I have 2 python interpreters installed on a windows 10 computer. Python 3.6 from ArcGIS pro 2.2 and Python 2.7 from ArcMap 10.6, using the `cmd` on Windows:

```
"C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/Scripts/propy" -c "import arcpy;print(arcpy.__path__)"
```

The output is:

```
'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\Resources\\ArcPy\\arcpy'
```

This is the intended result, but I need to do the same using `subprocess.Popen` from Python2.7 and also need to use `shell=True`

```
cmd = """ "C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/Scripts/propy" -c "import arcpy;print(arcpy.__path__)" """ 
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdout.read()
```

This will raise the error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
```

Basically the interpreter being used is Python2.7, I have tried to set `%PYYHONPATH%` to Python3.6 but still the same problem

Just a note, `propy` is a `.bat` that activates Python's virtualenv and therefore should be setting everything properly

How could I have the proper output using `subprocess.Popen` ?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem when trying to run python scripts within ArcGIS Workflow Manager within ArcGIS Pro. The problem is ArcGIS Workflow Manager loads up Python 2.X but we needed Python 3.X

To resolve the problem we added the following in our `__init__.py`

```py
import sys 

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    # When run through Workflow Manager 10.5, the PYTHONPATH environment 
    # variable is being set to the Python 2 environment, and that needs to be removed
    # when running in the Python 3 environment.
    sys.path = list(filter(lambda p: 'arcgis\\desktop' not in p, sys.path))
```